# Determine the closure of the difference of two affine hypersurfaces $\overline{Z(f)\backslash Z(g)}$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-varieties

Let $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ be the affine $n$-space over $k$. For two hypersufaces $Z(f)$ and $Z(g)$ of $\mathbb{A}_k^n$, where $f,g\in k[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$, what can we say about the Zarisky closure of their differences $\overline{Z(f)\backslash Z(g)}$?

More specifically, is $\overline{Z(f)\backslash Z(g)}$ also a hypersurface $Z(h)$ for some $h\in k[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$? How to determine $h$ from $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Have you tried out any examples? I think you would really benefit from that.

Comment: @KReiser I know a special case when $f$ has the form $f=g^dh$ such that $(g,h)=1$, then $\overline{Z(f)\backslash Z(g)}$ could be realized as $Z(h)$. I'm now wondering general cases.

Comment: The general case is just a slightly bigger version of that example. Can you upgrade $f=g^dh$ to something more general? For instance, with a $\gcd$?

Comment: @KReiser Yeah, I think $h$ is obtained from $f$ dividing all the prime factors appeared in $g$.

Comment: Let h be as @user498029 defined. You can use the fact that $V(h)\subset \overline{Z(f)\backslash Z(g)}$ can be checked locally and a localization of UFD by a single element $\neq0$ is still UFD.